# Undo old Extrude

Tags: modeling

How are you supposed to delete an old extrude? Undo is not an option as it was made to long ago. When I try to delete its vertices it deletes all the old face that I originally extruded from. Please help.

Comment: Post some screenshots of what you mean, it's hard to help with so little information. You can't just delete an "old extrude", blender doesn't generally keep a history of operations, you can however dissolve the extruded faces by selecting them and pressing X > Dissolve vertex. You'll will still have to reconstruct the original geometry if you extruded more than one contiguous face.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>A</kbd> (in edit mode) to select everything, then press <kbd>W</kbd> > <kbd>R</kbd> to remove doubles.